# Is my kernel broken and if so, how do I unbreak it?

Tags: boot, kernel, acpi

So I've been having a lot of trouble with my homelab server for the last couple of weeks. I originally installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and then foolishly decided to `dist-upgrade` to 22.04 LTS, which is where some of my problems began.

I was getting pretty good at fixing it all, but then the mainboard failed. Nothing was happening anymore. I swapped out the mainboard for a working one and that DID allow the machine to boot again, BUT:

**ever since then the server keeps randomly freezing**.

It's not a temperature thing - I kept printing CPU temps in the terminal until it froze and turns out it did so at 37°C. So hardware is most likely not to blame.

A live USB Pop_OS! kept running for like two days until I shut it down, so again: probably not a hardware thing, but rather something in Ubuntu. So I installed linux-crashdump and waited for the next freezing event.

Reading out the log:

```
sudo cat /var/crash/202401142245/dmesg.202401142245
```

Leads to a giant dumpfile that I've saved over at [Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/xgRHtg3X).

Here's the unfortunately unformatted dump leading to my two questions:

1. Is my kernel Fouled Up Beyond All Repair?
2. If yes, how do I repair my kernel?

> timon@nur1kleinerserver:/var/crash/202401142245$ sudo cat dmesg.202401142245

```
[sudo] password for timon: 
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xf4, date = 2023-02-22
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.0-91-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-045) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 14 13:30:08 UTC 2023 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-91.101-generic 5.15.131)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic root=UUID=e3292f62-8085-4a4e-afad-e81cb574b283 ro quiet splash crashkernel=512M-:192M vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000057fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000058000-0x0000000000058fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000059000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000403fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040400000-0x0000000070b3afff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000070b3b000-0x0000000070b3bfff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000070b3c000-0x0000000070b3cfff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000070b3d000-0x000000007a0cbfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a0cc000-0x000000007a560fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a561000-0x000000007a5a6fff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a5a7000-0x000000007a9c0fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a9c1000-0x000000007affdfff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007affe000-0x000000007affefff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007afff000-0x000000007fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000047effffff] usable
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x6a8f8018-0x6a908e57] usable ==> usable
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x6a8f8018-0x6a908e57] usable ==> usable
[    0.000000] extended physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000057fff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000058000-0x0000000000058fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000059000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000403fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000040400000-0x000000006a8f8017] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000006a8f8018-0x000000006a908e57] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000006a908e58-0x0000000070b3afff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000070b3b000-0x0000000070b3bfff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000070b3c000-0x0000000070b3cfff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000070b3d000-0x000000007a0cbfff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000007a0cc000-0x000000007a560fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000007a561000-0x000000007a5a6fff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000007a5a7000-0x000000007a9c0fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000007a9c1000-0x000000007affdfff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000007affe000-0x000000007affefff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000007afff000-0x000000007fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000047effffff] usable
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.70 by American Megatrends
[    0.000000] efi: TPMFinalLog=0x7a990000 ACPI 2.0=0x7a56f000 ACPI=0x7a56f000 SMBIOS=0x7ae08000 SMBIOS 3.0=0x7ae07000 MEMATTR=0x78515418 ESRT=0x7ae04e98 MOKvar=0x7ae23000 RNG=0x7a56e018 TPMEventLog=0x70c3c018 
[    0.000000] random: crng init done
[    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: Intel 0/NUC7i5BNB, BIOS BNKBL357.86A.0088.2022.0125.1102 01/25/2022
[    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2200.000 MHz processor
[    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2199.996 MHz TSC
[    0.000981] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000985] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.001000] last_pfn = 0x47f000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.001282] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT  
[    0.002573] last_pfn = 0x7afff max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.014062] esrt: Reserving ESRT space from 0x000000007ae04e98 to 0x000000007ae04ed0.
[    0.014077] Using GB pages for direct mapping
[    0.014848] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
[    0.014849] RAMDISK: [mem 0x6a909000-0x6e7adfff]
[    0.014858] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.014862] ACPI: RSDP 0x000000007A56F000 000024 (v02 INTEL )
```

Dump shortened to post here. Full dump over at pastebin.com

Per @zwets I used `glxinfo` to gather info about the display unit of the motherboard. It says:

> Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
> Device: Mesa Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics 640 (Kaby Lake GT3e) (KBL GT3) (0x5926)
> Version: 23.0.4
> Accelerated: yes
> Video memory: 15681MB
> Unified memory: yes
> Preferred profile: core (0x1)
> Max core profile version: 4.6
> Max compat profile version: 4.6
> Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
> Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
> OpenGL vendor string: Intel
> OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics 640 (Kaby Lake GT3e) (KBL GT3)
> OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
> OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60

So it might be a slightly different mainboard - but shouldn't the kernel be able to handle that?

Comment: The Linux kernel sits in packages (`linux-image-*.deb`) just like any other software on your Ubuntu system, so you could just reinstall it with an `apt reinstall` - except that if it indeed were "broken" (for most definitions of broken) you wouldn't be able to run that command for lack of a running machine. Anyway, your dump suggests (`RIP: 0010:__drm_atomic_helper_plane_destroy_state+0x54/0xb0 [drm_kms_helper]`) that the crash happens in the `drm_kms_helper` kernel module. This is related to your video card. Are you sure your replacement main board was identical to the old one?

Comment: I edited your question and removed Anglo-Saxon verbiage. I hope that still preserves your frustration. :D

Comment: When you're in grub, have you tried selecting Advanced Options and then picking an older kernel?  If you haven't, give it a try.

Comment: Ubuntu desktop sleeps by default.  If you use the console directly you probably won't notice as the keyboard will wake it up.  But if you are trying to use it remotely, you need to disable sleep.   This is almost certainly not a kernel thing.

Comment: Per @zwets I've had another look at my mainboard. It might actually not be exactly the same as before. The machine is an old Baby Canyon (ca. 2017) Intel NUC i5 and the replacement might actually have a slightly different SKU. Ubuntu's "System summary" says it doesn't know the display driver whereas `glxinfo` prints:

Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics 640 (Kaby Lake GT3e) (KBL GT3) (0x5926)
    Version: 23.0.4
    Accelerated: yes

But shouldn't in theory the kernel be able to handle that?

Comment: Not sure, but I could imagine that the initrd needs a rebuild after hardware changes. You could try an `update-initramfs -u` or reinstall of the `linux-image-*` package.

Comment: And check for selfmade Xorg.conf under `/etc/X11/` and `/usr/share/X11/`